# Protected Members of Other Instances in Scala

Tags: scala, protected

I just ran into a difficulty while learning Scala. I have an inheritance hierarchy that is essentially equivalent to this:

```
class A {
    protected def myMethod() = println("myMethod() from A")
}

class B extends A {
    def invokeMyMethod(a: A) = a.myMethod()
}
```

But trying to compile this sample, I get the error "test.scala:7: error: method myMethod cannot be accessed in A".

Coming from Java, my understanding is that protected members should be accessible at any point from a derived class, and nowhere have I seen anything that tells me that protected members in Scala are limited by instance. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> A protected identiﬁer x may be used as a member name in a selection r .x
>   only if one of the following applies:
>
> – The access is within the template deﬁning the member, or, if a qualiﬁcation C is given, inside the package C, or the class C, or its companion module, or
>
> – r is one of the reserved words this and super, or
>
> – r ’s type conforms to a type-instance of the class which contains the access.

These three rules define when exactly an instance is allowed to access another instance's protected members. One thing that's interesting to note is that, by the last rule, when `B` extends `A`, an instance of `A` may access protected members of a different instance of `B`... but an instance of `B` may not access protected members of another `A`! In other words:

```
class A {
    protected val aMember = "a"
    def accessBMember(b: B) = b.bMember // legal!
}

class B extends A {
    protected val bMember = "b"
    def accessAMember(a: A) = a.aMember // illegal!
}
```

Comment: This explanation doesn't actually say why the OP's code doesn't work.  `B` _is_ a derived type of `A`, just like it's supposed to be.

Comment: `B` is derived from `A`, but it is attempting to access not its own protected member `myMethod`, but instead that of another instance, the parameter `a: A`. A protected member is only visible to the _instance which contains it_ (by default, though this can be modified with the scoping annotation I mentioned).

Comment: That rather contradicts the passage you've quoted: "including other instances of the same type and any derived types."

Comment: @Submonoid - you're entirely correct, the quote isn't really applicable. Please see my edit to the response.

Comment: -1 This answer should be 3-5 sentences long. Everything before the EDIT is a waste of time.

Comment: @Kim Stebel - As a general rule I leave pre-edit material around so that comments referring to it don't become non-sequiturs, but I don't mind making an exception upon request... notice now that your comment makes no sense ;)