# Scala: Accessing protected field of companion object's trait

Tags: scala

I have a Trait, a Companion Object and a Class in Scala:

```
trait A {
    protected var foo = "Foo"
}

object B extends A {
}

class B {
     println(B.foo)
}
```

Why can't I access foo? I thought that foo would become a field of the object "B". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621853/protected-members-of-other-instances-in-scala

Comment: I think it's a different situation. I understand why an instance can't access protected fields on another instance. What I don't understand is detailed in my comment to Dominic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The spec says you can access protected members from:

> the companion module of any of those classes [that have the defining template as a base].

That is, not from the companion class of an object that has the defining template as a base.  Tricky.

This is not obvious because of the "module" nomenclature, where module simply means object.  There is occasional talk about changing that.  Although classes and modules can be companions, the relation is not symmetric; consider implicit search.

```
trait A {
  protected var foo = "Foo"
  protected def bar = "Bar"
}

object B extends A {
  //override protected var foo = super.foo // no
  override protected def bar = super.bar
}

class B {
  //println(B.foo) // no
  println(B.bar) // ok
}


class C extends A

object C {
  println(new C().foo)  // ok
}
```

Comment: From reading that section of the spec, it seems that if foo was defined in object B, class B should not be able to access it, but it can. Do you agree?

Comment: Not really: class-private is explicitly companion module or companion class. Hard to imagine protected removing an access. You may be right it should say "defining templ and companion". A protected member on an object is pathological except for the case you show; redefining the member on the object is a way of increasing visibility (for companion class); which is another reason not to define trait members as var (use defs).

Comment: So basically, if I wanted this to work, I would need to define foo as a def in A, and override foo in object B. Foo in object B would call Foo in A?

Comment: As shown. I had nearly changed it to def on the theory that SO snippets should always show best practice, modulo whatever misunderstanding the question might be demonstrating. This question should definitely go one someone's list of interview questions.

Answer (score 4):

Scala by default uses public fields. It also has private and protected. Private modifiers work the same as Java, but protected, works dramatically different.

The first difference is that protected can have two forms: `protected` and `protected[bar]`. Where `bar` can be a class, package or object.

From the [Scala language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> A protected identiﬁer x may be used as a member name in a selection r
>   .x only if one of the following applies:
>
> – The access is within the template deﬁning the member, or, if a
>   qualiﬁcation C is given, inside the package C, or the class C, or its
>   companion module, or
>
> – r is one of the reserved words this and super, or
>
> – r ’s type conforms to a type-instance of the class which contains
>   the access.

In other words, the **non-parameterized protected field is only visible from subclasses not from the same package**.

Comment: But isn't the field foo of object A essentially becoming a field of object B, because A is being mixed into B? And classes can access protected fields of their companion objects?

Comment: This quote is for the qualified access case, protected[C]. The unadorned case is the prev paragraph.  I agree with the OP that it is not obvious that companion module is different from companion class; there is ongoing talk about changing the nomenclature for this reason.